# How to create dynamic radiobuttons in CodenameOne

Tags: java, radio-button, components, codenameone

Using CodenameOne, I created an array of RadioButtons based on the count of records on a database table.

```
Container searchDisplayContainer = findMyContainer(f);

for(int i=0; i < records.length; i++) {
    RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();

    rdb.setName("rdb"+i);

    rdb.setText("rdb"+i);

    rdb.setGroup("locations"); 

    searchDisplayContainer.addComponent(rdb);
}
```

With this code, a number of RadioButtons are displayed on the simulator screen.

My problem is that after displaying the radiobuttons, I cannot check which one is selected.

Usually I can create the radiobutton in the theme.res and call it in the code with:

```
RadioButton rdb1 = findRadioButton(f);
```

and check if the button is selected with if(rdb1.isSelected)

However since I am not creating my radio buttons initially in the theme.res, I cannot use the `findRadioButton(f)` method.

My question is how do I create a number of RadioButtons within the code and then be able to check if they are selected after the submit button is pressed?

---

### Question Modification

```
package userclasses;

import generated.StateMachineBase;
import com.codename1.ui.*; 
import com.codename1.ui.events.*;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;

/**
*
* @author Your name here
*/
public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase {

    private Container searchDisplayContainer;
    private final int recordLength = 5;
    private ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    private RadioButton[] rdbs = new RadioButton[recordLength];

    public StateMachine(String resFile) {
        super(resFile);
    }

    /**
     * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of
     * the constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
     */
    protected void initVars(Resources res) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeMain(Form f) {
        searchDisplayContainer = findContainer1(f);

        for(int i=0;i<recordLength;i++){
            rdbs[i].setName("rdb"+i);
            rdbs[i].setText("rdb"+i);
            //add to button group
             bg.add(rdbs[i]);    
             //add to container
            searchDisplayContainer.addComponent(rdbs[i]);


        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMain_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(bg.getSelectedIndex());
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an instance of the `ButtonGroup` class and add the radio buttons to it in order to associate it to the other buttons in the group.

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for your tip however I did try using ButtonGroup before posting my initial question. I have modified the question to include a test scenario. As can be seen, I have created an instance of the ButtonGroup and also created arrays of RadioButtons. However when I click the Submit Buttton (onMain_ButtonAction). I get the error "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" and the simulator closes before displaying the radioButtons. I would like to be able to print the index of the selected radio button when the submit button is clicked. Please your insight. Thanks!

Comment: You get a NullPointerException because you allocated the array and didn't allocate the elements within it so rdbs[i] is null. Look at the stack it will actually say null pointer exception as well and point you at the specific line.